# Elasticsearch mapping with dynamic index_name

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I have simple repository to save my status log

```
class OrderStatusRepository
  include Elasticsearch::Persistence::Repository
  include Elasticsearch::Persistence::Repository::DSL

  def index_name
    "statuses-#{ Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m')}"
  end

  mapping do
    indexes :src_location, type: 'geo_point'
    indexes :dst_location, type: 'geo_point'
  end
end
```

The issue is mapping is not applied, when i add some data.

```
 {"id":158,"src_location":"1.486912, 2.493157","dst_location":"11.489026, -22.501309"}

"dst_location": {
  "type": "text", #NOT GEOPOINT !!!!
  "fields": {
    "keyword": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "ignore_above": 256
  }
}
```

I can create the index and mappings manually, but it has dynamic name and i'm not going to do it every month/day.

Is there any way to automate this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can use [index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/index-templates.html) that allow you to define templates
> that will automatically be applied on index creation time. The
> templates can include both settings and mappings.

For your data, you can create an index template like this which will match any indexes matching `foo-*` and `bar-*`

```
PUT/ _template/foobar

{
  "index_patterns": [
    "foo-*",
    "bar-*"
  ],
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "src_location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      },
      "dst_location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now create an index that will match the templates definition and add data to it

```
POST/ foo-1/_doc/1

{
  "id": 158,
  "src_location": "1.486912, 2.493157",
  "dst_location": "11.489026, -22.501309"
}
```

When you retrieve the mapping for the index. you will get this

```
GET /foo-1/_mapping

{
  "foo-1": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "dst_location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "src_location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```